# Story Identification about a world with no privacy after camera/network motes are released

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novel

I read this story/novel and remember liking it. Someone develops and releases nanoscopic motes that propagate and cover the whole planet  allowing people to see everything all people are doing.

It led to personality "shows" and vast social change for good (such as groups fighting corruption and crime by "watching").

I'm not sure, but it may have been multiversal and had squids in it.

I remember enjoying the ideas in it and sometimes find myself thinking about it when contemplating privacy today. I promise I'll reread it with more attention paid if someone can help me find it.

Comment: Reminds me of *Other Days, Other Eyes* by Bob Shaw, but that a novel, not multiversal and doesn't have squids (to my recollection).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like [Rudy Rucker’s *Postsingular*](http://www.rudyrucker.com/postsingular/). It was released under a Creative Commons Licence and is [available online](http://www.rudyrucker.com/postsingular/cc_downloads/).

It has cuttlefish, but no squids as far as I can remember.

> “Planktonic sea creatures rarely swim,” said Craigor. “Like
>   cuttlefish, they go with the flow. Until something nearby catches
>   their attention. And then—dart! Another meal, another lover, another
>   masterpiece.”
>
> Just aft of the cleared area was Craigor’s holding tank, an aquarium
>   hand-caulked from car windshields, bubbling with air and containing a
>   few dozen Pharaoh cuttlefish, their body-encircling fins undulating in
>   an endless hula dance, their facial squid-bunches of tentacles
>   gathered into demure sheaves, their yellow W-shaped pupils gazing at
>   their captors.
>
> “They look so smart and so—doomed,” said Nektar, regarding the
>   bubbling tank. Her face was still sensuous and beautiful, her
>   blond-tinted hair lustrous. But the set of her mouth had turned a bit
>   hard and frown-wrinkles shadowed her brow. Jil gathered that Ond and
>   Nektar didn’t get along all that well. Nektar had never really
>   forgiven her husband for the nants. “The cuttlefish are like wizards
>   on death row,” continued Nektar. “They make me feel guilty about my
>   webeyes.”

Comment: Fantastic! Cuttlefish and squid... I'll have to do a comparative study. Thanks for answering this question - I've really been looking forward to rereading this book and it's CC online - even better!